# Running python script in node.js SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, child-process, homekit

Attempting to run a python script throw child_process. Receiving a SyntaxError..
 In a nut shell im trying to create an "accessory" for homekit that executes Python script when value is true and a separate python script that runs for false value. Suggestions for a javascript noob?

....

The SyntaxError

```
/root/HAP-NodeJS-master/accessories/Light_accessory.js:85
                format: "bool",
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at accessories (/root/HAP-NodeJS-master/Core.js:21:24)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/HAP-NodeJS-master/Core.js:19:53)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
root@raspberrypi:~/HAP-NodeJS-master#
```

........

CODE

```
// HomeKit types required
var types = require("./types.js")
var exports = module.exports = {};
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var execute = function (accessory, characteristic, value) {
    console.log("executed accessory: " + accessory + ", and characteristic: " + characteristic + ", with value: " + value + ".");
}

exports.accessory = {
    displayName: "Light 1",
    username: "1A:2B:3C:4D:5E:FF",
    pincode: "031-45-154",
    services: [{
        sType: types.ACCESSORY_INFORMATION_STYPE,
        characteristics: [{
            cType: types.NAME_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Light 1",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.MANUFACTURER_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Oltica",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.MODEL_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Rev-1",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.SERIAL_NUMBER_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "A1S2NASF88EW",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.IDENTIFY_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pw"],
            format: "bool",
            initialValue: false,
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Identify Accessory",
            designedMaxLength: 1
        }]
    }, {
        sType: types.LIGHTBULB_STYPE,
        characteristics: [{
            cType: types.NAME_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: null,
            perms: ["pr"],
            format: "string",
            initialValue: "Light 1",
            supportEvents: false,
            supportBonjour: false,
            manfDescription: "Bla",
            designedMaxLength: 255
        }, {
            cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE,
            onUpdate: function (value) {
                exec('python /home/pi/Desktop/Projects/Lights/on.py' + value, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                });
                perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
                format: "bool",
                initialValue: false,
                supportEvents: false,
                supportBonjour: false,
                manfDescription: "Turn On the Light",
                designedMaxLength: 1
            },
            {
                cType: types.HUE_CTYPE,
                onUpdate: function (value) {
                    console.log("Change:", value);
                    execute("Test Accessory 1", "Light - Hue", value);
                },
                perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
                format: "int",
                initialValue: 0,
                supportEvents: false,
                supportBonjour: false,
                manfDescription: "Adjust Hue of Light",
                designedMinValue: 0,
                designedMaxValue: 360,
                designedMinStep: 1,
                unit: "arcdegrees"
            },
            {
                cType: types.BRIGHTNESS_CTYPE,
                onUpdate: function (value) {
                    console.log("Change:", value);
                    execute("Test Accessory 1", "Light - Brightness", value);
                },
                perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
                format: "int",
                initialValue: 0,
                supportEvents: false,
                supportBonjour: false,
                manfDescription: "Adjust Brightness of Light",
                designedMinValue: 0,
                designedMaxValue: 100,
                designedMinStep: 1,
                unit: "%"
            },
            {
                cType: types.SATURATION_CTYPE,
                onUpdate: function (value) {
                    console.log("Change:", value);
                    execute("Test Accessory 1", "Light - Saturation", value);
                },
                perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
                format: "int",
                initialValue: 0,
                supportEvents: false,
                supportBonjour: false,
                manfDescription: "Adjust Saturation of Light",
                designedMinValue: 0,
                designedMaxValue: 100,
                designedMinStep: 1,
                unit: "%"
            }]
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me reindent the problematic part, so you can see more easily what is going wrong. The marked line contains two characters that are not in your code.

```
{
  cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE,
  onUpdate:
    function (value) {
      exec('python /home/pi/Desktop/Projects/Lights/on.py' + value,
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        }
      );
    },                          // <---- MISSING
  perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
  format: "bool",
  ....
```

Without brace and comma, the object is interpreted in your code as:

```
{
  cType: types.POWER_STATE_CTYPE,
  onUpdate:
    function (value) {
      exec('python /home/pi/Desktop/Projects/Lights/on.py' + value,
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        }
      );
      perms: ["pw", "pr", "ev"],
      format: "bool",
      ....
```

Here, `perms:` is taken as a label, `["pw", "pr", "ev"], format` as an expression (which is also a statement), and then you find a `:` which should never follow a statement, but only either a key inside an object, or a label before a statement; and neither can be an expression. Hence the syntax error.

Comment: That Fix it! Thank you. I have one more question if you dont mind?Right now its turning the light on but not off. So the value false needs to be implemented as well. Kind of like this                                             ?php
    if(isset($_GET['trigger']) && $_GET['trigger'] == 1) {
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  exec('python /home/off.py');
 }
 if(isset($_GET['trigger']) && $_GET['trigger'] == 2) {
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  exec('python /home/on.py');
 }
?>                                                                    How would you accomplish that in javascript?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you're asking. I suggest you create a new question for this.